# Collapsing app bar not reaching the parent container

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have this collapsing app layout that has a default margin at the right which I'm trying to remove. I have tried everything but non-removed it. I even added a negative margin but still not removing it. Please how can I remove the margin?

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_height="94dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/clay_background"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapsed_appbar"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/expanded_appbar"
                app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="0dp">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:background="@color/blueDark"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider_view"
                    android:layout_width="2000dp"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/redDark"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="-100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        

       
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is the image.

[image]